# Bootstrap Toggle with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I'm using bootstrap-toggle in one of the forms in ASP.NET:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="IsValidated" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Validated" data-off="Not Validated" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" value="Y" >
```

But when switching on the toggle, and check the state of the checkbox in the code behind after posting the form, always I find that the checkbox is not checked!

How to capture the state of the checkbox?

Comment: Share your server side code for checking checkbox state. Also, I think you should add name attribute in your checkbox and then try accessing its value using Request.Form[“checkbox name”]

Comment: I have tested that after adding the name attribute, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add name attribute to your checkbox element

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsValidated" id="IsValidated" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Validated" data-off="Not Validated" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" value="Y" >
```

Access the checkbox value on server side using

```
Request.Form["IsValidated"]
```